# Unable to create a new Azure VM in most regions

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

Unable to create Azure VM in most regions. I am talking about general purpose "D" series.
From the drop down list of sizes....they are "greyed out". If I choose a region such as Australia central... there is no problem. I found a few threads speaking about the same issue from 2020. Are new VM's not being provisioned in certain regions like West US or East US?

Comment: Welcome! This is something you need to bring up with Support. Not really something that can be covered here, since it's related to service availability.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to restrictions on your subscription on which regions you can use. You will want to raise a support ticket to have them open up other regions.